# IIS 401.1 error

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

We have a .net web application running on iis 8 using windows authentication.
Everything was working fine until we installed a new version of our application without any changes to the iis settings or in the apps web.config file. 
The problem is that ever since when we try to open up the app in a browser and fill out the windows authentication popup with valid user user information, it just wont authenticate and after the third try we get a 401.1 error message. This happens when we try to access the website from any pc even the pc that hosts iis and even when we try to launch the site through iis.
Any ideas on what could cause such a thing?

Comment: From what you are saying, I am guessing that your site is Authenticating (Windows accepts login) but it is not authorizing which means that the authenticated user does not have permissions to view the page. Did the app upgrade add a security role that the users must be included in to see the page?

Comment: I'm not really sure if its authenticating me or not because after I press enter on the authentication popup another one appears and after i enter my user\pass again it does that for a third time then i get a 401 error.
The upgrade shouldnt've changed any iis settings and the web.config is exactly the same as the previous version's

Comment: in IIS, check your authentication settings for the site, click on Windows Authentication and select providers on the menu on the right. Verify that the provider is correct and in the right order (remove any you don't need).  Otherwise, I would suggest checking the browser security settings and make sure your site is trusted.